# Converting yyyymdd to yyyymmdd using SSIS

Tags: sql, sql-server, date, ssis

I a column which has dates in `yyyymdd` and `yyyymmdd` format. I want to convert the yyyymdd to yyyymmdd.

for example I have dates `2022520` and `20220520`. how can I convert 202250 to 20220520 using SSIS?

I tired the following

1. using len I counted the number of characters
2. then used if condition to add 0 before 5 in "2022520".
   `[Character count]==7 ? "0"+ Substring([Extract Date],5,2) : [Extract Date]`
3. result of this expression `052`

Comment: So 2022115 transform to   2022-11-05 or 2022-01-15  ?

Comment: 2022115 transform to 2022-11-05

Comment: @JohnCappelletti: 2022-01-15. As to the sample data, 2022-11-15 will be 20221115.

Comment: @Gustav You've added an extra 1.   DSHAH's response is contradictory .   As is, there is no answer, this is the trouble with ambiguous dates.

Comment: @JohnCappelletti: Yes, the comment from the questioneer adds confusion.

Answer (score 0):

Better it would be when you dsave dates in a proper date clumn in the right format

Eveything else is costly

```
CREATE TABLE test
    ([ExtractDate] varchar(8))
;
    
INSERT INTO test
    ([ExtractDate])
VALUES
    ('2022205'),
    ('20221231'),
    ('2021115')
;
```

```
3 rows affected
```

```
SELECT LEFT([ExtractDate],4) +
  RIGHT('00' + LEFT(
SUBSTRING([ExtractDate], 5, LEN([ExtractDate]))
,LEN(SUBSTRING([ExtractDate], 5, LEN([ExtractDate]))) -2),2)
  + RIGHT([ExtractDate],2)
FROM test
```

| (No column name) |
| --- |
| 20220205 |
| 20221231 |
| 20210115 |

[fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/1juHXdlN)

Answer (score 0):

You can use this expression:

```
Left([Extract Date], 4) + Right('00' + Right([Extract Date], Len([Extract Date]) - 4), 4)
```

Example:

```
2022520     20220520
20221231    20221231
20220520    20220520
```